# SvelteKit environment variables special character ($) issue

Tags: javascript, typescript, vite, sveltekit

Any ideas of a workaround without removing `$`?

Environment Variable: **DB_PASS**

.env file
`DB_PASS = *^$php&!Bz`

from '$env/static/private'
`DB_PASS = *^&!Bz`

Seemingly culprit character
`$`

env file

[image: env file]

env console log

[image: env log]

Comment: Have you tried escaping it somehow, like `\$` or `$$`? Or do you want to avoid that? (Which would be reasonable as it could easily lead to configuration errors.)

Comment: Thanks HB! GitHub was able to resolve it just before you posted, added answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, thanks to the [GitHub community](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/9092).

> Vite uses dotenv-expand to expand variables out of the box.
>
> Note that if you want to use `$` inside your environment value, you have to escape it with `\`.

https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files